# Two-way conversion between integers and Peano naturals

Tags: scala, types, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

I am using a standard type-encoding of natural numbers in Scala. For the purpose of this question, the following definition will do:

```
sealed trait Nat
sealed trait _0 extends Nat
sealed trait Succ[N <: Nat] extends Nat
```

I can use the compiler to convert these `Nat` types into actual numbers, for instance by defining

```
class NatConverter[N <: Nat](val n: Int)

implicit val zeroConv: NatConv[_0] = new NatConv(0)
implicit def succConv[N <: Nat](implicit ev: NatConv[N]): NatConv[Succ[N]] =
  new NatConv(ev.n + 1)

def nat2value[N <: Nat](implicit ev: NatConv[N]) = ev.n
```

This works:

```
type _1 = Succ[_0]
type _2 = Succ[_1]
nat2value[_2] // gives 2
```

I am trying to invert this correspondence, if possible at all, by exploiting dependent method return types. So, the first thing a need is a container for an `Int` and a `Nat`

```
trait Pair {
    type N <: Nat
    def n: Int
}
```

Now, I would like to be able to implicitly convert an `Int` to an instance of `Pair`, with the right value for `N`. Here it is

```
implicit def int2pair(a: Int): Pair =
    if (a == 0) new Pair {
        type N = _0
        val n = 0
    }
    else {
        val previous = int2pair(a - 1)
        new Pair {
            type N = Succ[previous.N]
            val n = a
        }
    }
```

This does compile. Unfortunately

```
val two = int2pair(2)
implicitly[two.N =:= _2]
```

fails, as well as

```
val two = int2pair(2)
implicitly[two.N <:< _2]
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the *return type* of `int2pair` is just `Pair`, not `Pair { type N = _2 }`. The `if`/`else` happens at runtime, the compiler can't know which branch will be taken.

AFAIK the only way to go from value to type is with a macro. You might want to look at [shapeless' singleton support](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala).

Comment: Yes, I know I can go with a macro, but I was trying to see how far I could go without. In retrospective, it is pretty obvious that the type is just `Pair`, but it seemed reasonable before :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: Minor quibble: the only way to go from a _non-reference_ value to a singleton type is via a macro. This might change in Scala 2.12.x with the introduction of SIP-23 (aka 42.type).